# Oracle. Execute stored procedure on creation of the view

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-view

I have a `view` with a certain `field`.
Now I need to modify this field accordingly to some logic. I've implemented this logic in a `stored procedure`.

Now I want to execute this stored procedure and its result should be placed in a `field` of a `view`.

Procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "ORDTEST"."DEPARTMENT_FULLPATH"
(depId IN VARCHAR2, path OUT VARCHAR2)
...
```

So it has one input parameter and one output parameter.

In a `view` I need something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW kcv_journal_contract_reg AS
   ...
   SELECT DEPARTMENT_FULLPATH(field1),
   ...
```

Comment: I've just read about not being able to call stored procedure from this context. So remaked procedure into function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yegoshin Maxim given good solution for this.

you can return the desired value inplace of OUT parameter..

```
create or replace function "ORDTEST"."DEPARTMENT_FULLPATH" (depId IN VARCHAR2)
return VARCHAR2 as 
....
return path ;
```